# JavaScript: Properties of ResizeObserverEntry.contentRect are set to 0/incorrect

Tags: javascript, resize, getboundingclientrect, resize-observer

I have a resize observer re-positioning a div to overlay another element, and at first I tried to use the left and top properties of the ResizeObserver entry to position the div, but after some debugging I found that those properties were set to 0.

Unfortunately, I was not able to exactly replicate the problem within a stackoverflow snippet, and now all of the properties seem to be off, but `getBoudingClientRect` did work correctly when tried in the snippet, and in my original program, the `right` and `bottom` properties were correct.

```js
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  const boundingRect = entries[0].contentRect;
  console.log(boundingRect.x, boundingRect.y, boundingRect.top, boundingRect.left);

  div.style.left = boundingRect.left + "px";
  div.style.top = boundingRect.top + "px";
  div.style.width = boundingRect.width + "px";
  div.style.height = boundingRect.height + "px";
});
observer.observe(button);
```

```css
#button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00000055;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">some text</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

From my understanding the `contentRect` object is supposed to be the same as using `getBoundingClientRect`, but as you can see from the snippet, it is far from correct. (no rhyme intended)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a partial answer to my problem on the [ResizeObserver spec page](https://www.w3.org/TR/resize-observer/#create-and-populate-resizeobserverentry-h):

> 7. If target is not an SVG element do these steps:
>    Set this.contentRect.top to target.padding top.
>    Set this.contentRect.left to target.padding left.
> 8. If target is an SVG element do these steps:
>    Set this.contentRect.top and this.contentRect.left to 0.

Although this explains the "incorrect" coordinates, my original element was a normal div, not an SVG element, and the purpose for setting the left and right properties to 0 for SVGs is a mystery to me.

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot my issue. Whether padding is allowed (not svg) or not (svg), the result in both situations is that the `top` prop is different from that returned by `getBoundingClientRect`.